# Figma - Carousel Slide

Tags: user-interface, button, carousel, slide, figma

Iam new to UI design in figma, I designed a carousel slide with button and automatic for my project app. In the total of four carousel slide, First two slides are working correctly, but in next two slides, the scrolling button is also sliding along with the image. The image can slide automatically, but the arrow button should not.

I added the link to the prototype.(https://www.figma.com/proto/J7jrkQz18eRVGpPtJxyEdi/Untitled?type=design&node-id=120-3&t=n0yzUbRP1d1ZgY9K-1&scaling=scale-down&page-id=85%3A2&mode=design)

I tried the automatic carousel for image, but the button also included in that somehow after the second image.